# Formatting a Linux path in C#

Tags: c#

So I am making a file browser using the WinSCP library in C#. The files and folders from the remote server are loaded into a ListView, and I have an event on the ListView_DoubleClick event that will go and get the files for that folder. However my problem is, the "CurrentPath" returned from WinSCP is built like so;
"/eddata/T". Now if a user goes back up a directory, the path returned is "/eddata/T/../". If the user then goes into another folder called "Bob", the path now looks like; "/eddata/T/../Bob".

I want a way so I can display the current path in a user friendly way. So when a user is in the directory; "/eddata/T/" and they go up a level, a label should tell them they are in; "/eddata/";

This is my attempt but isn't working as expected, it doesn't deal the event where a user goes back up two directories at the same time;

```
private string FormatPathString(string input)
{

    String working = input;

    bool replacement = true;
    while (replacement)
    {
        string[] splits = working.Split('/');
        splits = splits.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x != String.Empty).ToArray();

        int? found_index = null;

        for (int i = splits.Count() - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (splits[i] == "..")
            {
                found_index = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (found_index.HasValue)
        {
            replacement = true;
            splits = splits.Where((val, idx) => (idx != found_index) && (idx != found_index - 1)).ToArray();
            working = String.Join("/", splits);
        }
        else
        {
            replacement = false;
        }

    }

    return working;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Path class.

```
string pathWithDots= "/eddata/T/../Bob";

string pathWithoutDots = Path.GetFullPath(pathWithDots); // Result: c:\eddata\Bob
```

however the Path class assumes that you are using a windows path and adds C: and changes slashes to backslashes so you will need to remove the C: at the start and replace all back slashes with forward slashes.

```
string pathNx = pathWithoutDots.Substring(2).Replace("\\", "/"); // Result: /eddata/Bob
```

Comment: Might I add your solution has issues with paths containing spaces.  He said he's using it to create a WinSCP client browser in which any number of possibilities could exist both locally and remote for path names. You may want to consider offering up a more complete solution.

Comment: ``string pathNx = (pathWithoutDots.Substring(2).Replace("\\", "/")).Replace(" ", "\\ ");``  will properly escape spaces.